# I wrote a program to add two matrices but it's not working. Any suggestions for what's wrong?

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

This program takes two arrays from the user and adds them and prints the sum. The program uses nested for loops to take the values and print the values. The compiler is returning the error array1 not declared in this scope. The program also stops working if I remove the sum printing part. Any suggestions to shorten the program appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int a,b;

int i,j;

main()
{

    printf("Enter the size of the array  \n Rows : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Columns : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    int array[a][b];

    printf("Enter the values of the %dx%d array : \n",a,b);

    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("The values of the First Matrix are :\n");


    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",array[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    int input;
    printf("If you want to do further operations on Matrices press 1\n");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    if(input==1)
    {
        printf("Enter the size of the array  \n Rows : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Columns : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    int array1[a][b];

    printf("Enter the values of the %dx%d array : \n",a,b);

    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&array1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("The values of the Second Matrix are :\n");


    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",array1[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    }


    input = 0;
    printf("If you want to add the two matrices press 1 \n");
    scanf("%d",input);

    int array2[a][b];

    if(input==1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
            array2[i][j] =  array[i][j]+array1[i][j];
        }
    }

    }

    printf("The Sum of the first and Second array is : \n ");


    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",array2[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

Comment: `main()` <- what? standard prototypes are  `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, void **argv)`. Implementations are free to support other prototypes as well, but simply `main()` is very unlikely to be correct.

Comment: Apart from that, and without looking at the code: It would help **you** to do some debugging yourself first. There's a nice blog post [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to guide you. If you're still stuck, it will also help you creating a [mcve], which will in turn help others to quickly understand the concrete problem and give help to the point.

Comment: @FelixPalmen The program does not compile, so debugging instructions will not help at this point.

Comment: _The compiler is returning the error array1 not declared in this scope ?_  Because `array1` is declared inside `if(input==1)` block and you are accessing outside that scope.

Comment: @PascalCuoq the question text is unclear about that. It also says "it stops working when ...", so how can it work when it doesn't compile?

Comment: Most likely you have a variable in too tight a scope, which would be obvious had you followed one of the standard patterns for indenting your code.  (I use the K & R style but without a space between a `)` and a `{`).

Comment: @FelixPalmen The program worked when the adding was removed. But the program stopped working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lot of problem in the code, advise you to use curly braces `{..}` properly. Also use `int main(void) {   }` instead of just `main() {  }`.

*The compiler is returning the error array1 not declared in this scope ?* Because `array1` is declared inside `if(input==1)` block and you are accessing outside that scope.

Also  statement `scanf("%d",input);` is wrong, it gives the warning, compile your program with `-Wall` flag.

And finally avoid using global variable for this small tasks or use `#define` to define `row` and `column` value.

Here is modified code

```
int main() {
        printf("Enter the size of the array  \n Rows : ");
        int a = 0,b = 0;
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("Columns : ");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        int array[a][b];
        printf("Enter the values of the %dx%d array : \n",a,b);

        for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
                        scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
                }
        }
        printf("The values of the First Matrix are :\n");
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
                        printf("%d\t",array[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
        int input;
        printf("If you want to do further operations on Matrices press 1\n");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        if(input==1) {
                printf("Enter the size of the array  \n Rows : ");
                scanf("%d",&a);
                printf("Columns : ");
                scanf("%d",&b);
                int array1[a][b];
                printf("Enter the values of the %dx%d array : \n",a,b);
                for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                        for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
                                scanf("%d",&array1[i][j]);
                        }
                }
                printf("The values of the Second Matrix are :\n");
                for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                        for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
                                printf("%d\t",array1[i][j]);
                        }
                        printf("\n");
                }

                input = 0;
                printf("If you want to add the two matrices press 1 \n");
                scanf("%d",&input);/* use &input */
                int array2[a][b];
                if(input==1) {
                        for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                                for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
                                        array2[i][j] =  array[i][j]+array1[i][j];
                                }
                        }
                }
                printf("The Sum of the first and Second array is : \n ");
                for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                        for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
                                printf("%d\t",array2[i][j]);
                        }
                        printf("\n");
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you ask to use main(void) istead of main()

Comment: C standard says  that. The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
parameters:
`int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
or with `two` parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
`int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Always compile your program with `-Wall` flag & don't ignore compiler warnings for e.g `gcc -Wall test.c`

Comment: I use the IDE Dev C++

Answer (score 0):

You declare array1 in block beginning with:

```
if(input==1)
```

Then you try to use it outside that block, which gives you the compiler error.

```
array2[i][j] =  array[i][j]+array1[i][j];
```

The fastest solution would be to nest the code following the blok inside it, so `array1` stays in scope.